# information class part shows an error==>bound method error & int object is not callable"

Tags: python

Information Class uses the marks from Employee class and the Date Of Joining date from the Joining Detail class to calculate the top 3 Employees based on their Ratings and then Display, using read Data, all the details on these employees in Ascending order of their Date Of Joining.

I am unable to retrieve top 3 employees based on ratings. Is `sorted()` method works here or any other method to use?

```
from datetime import date

class Employee():
    num_emp=input("Enter the number of employees: ")
    Gender=""
    Salary=0 
    PerformanceRating=0

    def __init__(self,Gender,Salary,PerformanceRating):
        self.EmployeeID =input("Enter employeeid: ")
        self.Gender = Gender
        self.Salary = Salary
        self.PerformanceRating = PerformanceRating
    def get(self):
        print("EmployeeID\t:", self.EmployeeID, "Employee Gender\t:", self.Gender, "Employee Salary\t:", self.Salary, "Employee PerformanceRating:", self.PerformanceRating)

class Joiningdetail():
    DateOfJoining= date(year=int(input("year: ")), month=int(input("month:")), day=int(input("day:")))
    def __init__ (self,DateOfJoining):  
        self.DateOfJoining=DateOfJoining
        
    def getDoJ(self):
      print("Employee DOJ is:", self.DateOfJoining)

class Information(Employee,Joiningdetail):
  def __init__(self,Gender,Salary,PerformanceRating):
    super().__init__(self,Salary,PerformanceRating)
  def readData(self,PerformanceRating):
      #self.PerformanceRating.sort()
      sorted(PerformanceRating())
  def displayData(self,DateOfJoining):
      print(self.getDoJ)



emp1=Employee("Female",34343,2)
emp1.get()
doj_emp1=Joiningdetail((2004, 3, 4))
doj_emp1.getDoJ()

emp2=Employee("Female",34579,4)
emp2.get()
doj_emp2=Joiningdetail((2000, 5, 7))
doj_emp2.getDoJ()

emp3=Employee("Male",34982,4)
emp3.get()
doj_emp3=Joiningdetail((2001, 9, 10))
doj_emp3.getDoJ()

emp4=Employee("Male",34579,4)
emp4.get()
doj_emp4=Joiningdetail((2020, 5, 6))
doj_emp4.getDoJ()


top3_rating= Information("Male",34000,4,)
top3_rating.displayData(5)

print (top3_rating.readData(3))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The program includes a class called employee which contains three private numbers name of type string, age of type Integer, a salary of type float, a function set_data () to read class elements and a get_data () to print the above information based on salary a function year_salary () to print the yearly salary for the employee. An increment of 30% of the employee's salary is given if the employee's age ranges between 45-74. Note: Enter information about three employees (use array)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33380566)

Answer (score 1):

You can use .sort() to sort a list.
Be advised that this line of code `top3_rating= Information("Male",34000,4,)` is an integer and not a list, and you can't sort an int :)
Send the list. of users you want to preform your code on.

I'm still trying to figure out what you want to do with your code.
It looks like you do not have a data structure with the `Employee data` in it. When you do your `.get()` call for every employee created, try to append it to a list (or a tuple if you do not want to perform changes in the data).

It looks like you want to have a top3 object:

```py
top3_rating = Information("Male", 34000, 4, )
top3_rating.displayData(5)
```

But you are referring to a class object that is another kind go employee, instead of a list or some kind of data manager.

Comment: ```from __future__ import print_function
class Information(Employee,Joiningdetail):
  def __init__(self,Gender,Salary,PerformanceRating):
    super().__init__(Gender,Salary,PerformanceRating)
  def readData(self,PerformanceRating):
      #self.PerformanceRating.sort()
      list(str(PerformanceRating)).sort()
  def displayData(self,DateOfJoining):
      print(self.getDoJ)

top3_rating= Information("Male","34000","4")
top3_rating.displayData(5)

print (top3_rating.readData(3))```

Comment: I got bound error as well as none...now it is not throwing an error like before "int object is not callable". But still the output is none. Please correct me if my understanding is wrong from your inputs. Thank you

Comment: First, what version of python are you using that you need to import "print"?
Second, and more important, what is your goal with ```Information``` class?

Comment: Using python 3.8....Information Class uses the members from Employee class and the DateOfJoining date from the JoiningDetail class to calculate the top 3 Employees based on their Ratings and then Display, using readData, all the details on these employees in Ascending order of their Date Of Joining.

Comment: print function sometimes says tuple object is not callable.so I googled it and found to import print function

Comment: I am getting confused to get the desired output.so am trying in many ways. I am not able to understand the real problem of error in the code.

Comment: So the problem with your error code (int not callable) is that you try to access an integer as an iterable object (eg list, tuple..). fix the kind of object into one that you can iterate on.